# Strange path URI in tomcat access log

Tags: tomcat, wso2, tomcat7, wso2-api-manager

I'm using api manager 2.1.0 and trying to test the java SDK generated via the store application.
When I look at the catalina access log of my back end service, I notice a strange URI:

```
myIP - - [18/Apr/2017:17:14:25 +0100] "^V^C^C^@Å^A^@^@Á^C^CXö;a<89>%l«8ÆWu­ª<9a>:^BÆ<9b>þpÿ^SA^_<96><88><9a>±K¡Ô^@^@:À#À'^@<À%À)^@g^@@À À^S^@/À^DÀ^N^@3^@2À+À/^@<9c>À-À1^@<9e>^@¢À^HÀ^R^@ " 400 -
myIP - - [18/Apr/2017:17:17:31 +0100] "^V^C^C^@Å^A^@^@Á^C^CXö<^[éq^W(<8b>^SyLµµ^?Ã+çÁ;á<9c> iä^X<80><93>^E<è¢^@^@:À#À'^@<À%À)^@g^@@À À^S^@/À^DÀ^N^@3^@2À+À/^@<9c>À-À1^@<9e>^@¢À^HÀ^R^@" 400 -
```

Any explication please about this URI?
Thanks

Comment: what you mean by "trying to test the java SDK generated via the store application. "

Comment: It is a feature provided by wso2 api manager which consist of providing a java client to call REST APIs